# Can't run C program from shell

Tags: macos, bash

I've programmed my first program, typical one calculating the triangle square with Xcode and TextWrangler, and then I want to run it but I can't.

When I try to run it, Terminal says *Command not found* every time…

```
MacBook-Pro:~ Gaspar$ /Users/Gaspar/Desktop/prova.c 
-bash: /Users/Gaspar/Desktop/prova.c: Permission denied
MacBook-Pro:~ Gaspar$ sudo /Users/Gaspar/Desktop/prova.c 
sudo: /Users/Gaspar/Desktop/prova.c: command not found
```

How could I configure it so I don't have to enter the directory all the time?

Comment: Have you compiled the program?

Comment: @LucasKauffman yes, with gcc and Xcode.

Comment: You need to run the compiled binary executable (probably `prova`), not your source code (certainly *not* `prova.c`, which is just plain text and not a script/binary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `prova.c` is a source file. It's plain-text and contains your program's source code. Once you've compiled it, a new file will be created, probably `prova` (with no extension). This is the executable – a binary file – which you can run from your terminal.

Many executables in your shell are available everywhere, without having to type the full path. For example, `sudo`, is actually `/usr/bin/sudo`, but your shell will know to search in `/usr/bin`. However, your own programs are not automatically found by the shell. You'll have to tell it where it is.

Simply type:

```
/Users/Gaspar/Desktop/prova
```

If you don't want to write the full path, just change your working directory before:

```
cd /Users/Gaspar/Desktop/
```

Now you can call your program like this, where `.` specifies the current directory. You'll have to include the `./` since your current directory normally is not in the list of paths where your shell searches for executable programs.

```
./prova
```

This might not work if the binary does not have execute rights set. This is a flag that allows the file to be run from a terminal. If you get a *permission denied* error, add the execute permission:

```
chmod +x prova
```

Now, try running the file again with `./prova`.

Answer (score 2):

```
gcc /Users/Gaspar/Desktop/prova.c -o Users/Gaspar/Desktop/prova
/Users/Gaspar/Desktop/prova
```

make sure it have executable flag set (it should have by default) if not set it:

```
ls -l Users/Gaspar/Desktop/prova

chmod +x Users/Gaspar/Desktop/prova
```